# Conditional Formatting in Access 2007 Report

Tags: ms-access, reporting

I have created two reports in Access 2007 that are virtually identical except for the data source.  In both of them I have set up conditional formatting on a field to make the font italic when

```
Expression is [Status]="Holding"
```

In one of the reports the conditional formatting is applied and in the other it isn't.  I've even tried setting it to

```
Expression is [Status]=[Status]
```

but the conditional formatting still isn't applied.  Any ideas on what is going wrong?

Comment: does that have to be wrapped in parenthesis?

Comment: If its working in one and not the other, are you definitely sure that the other data source has "Holding" values? Can you test that.

Comment: @Pace Yes, both data sources have "Holding" in them.  When I create a query that filters for rows with [Status]="Holding", multiple rows are returned.

Comment: @Raj More Enclosing it in parentheses didn't help.

Comment: Have your tried specifying the field explicitly e.g Fields("Status").value = "Holding"? Also you might want to trim off white space which could invalidate your comparison.

Answer (score 1):

I cleared the conditional formatting from all the text boxes where it was set.  I then again set the conditional formatting to

```
Expression is [Status]="Holding"
```

This time it worked!  Very strange, but at least it's working now.

Comment: If you copy conditional formatting of the form Status = "Holding", it will work in the original, but get changed to "Status" = "Holding" in the destination you're copying to. You have to explicitly put in the square brackets for field/control references. I learned this just last week, as I've not used conditional formatting much. I honestly think it's a pretty half-baked feature that needs to be revised to be as useful as it should be. The screen painting issues are also pretty annoying and unprofessional looking, but, unfortunately, it's the only way to accomplish certain things.

Answer (score 0):

I found this helpful excerpt on the [Office website](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/change-the-appearance-of-a-control-by-using-conditional-formatting-HA010208133.aspx#BMexpressionis):

> **Before you begin**
>       When you use an expression to apply conditional formatting, you should make sure that > the controls being formatted do not use the same
>   names as any of the fields in the form's or report's underlying record
>   source. If you refer to a field in an expression and there is a
>   control by the same name on the form or report, Access is unable to
>   determine whether you are referring to the control or to the field.
>   Because of this, Access cannot evaluate the expression. As a result,
>   the conditional formatting is not applied, and the control appears
>   with its default formatting. Whenever you add expressions to a form or
>   report, it is very important that you rename any controls whose names
>   conflict with field names that are used in the expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Be also careful with the 'BackStyle' property of the control.  If you use a form wizard and default style template the backstyle may be transparent - which means that conditional formatting with a backcolor does nothing.